# Bootstrap-select not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2 and want to implement  element to look like dropdown-menu. There is a solution in github: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select

My code:

```
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $( function() {
       $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    })
</script>
```

It doesn't work. But when i type

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

in console in Chrome DevTools - select changes to dropdown and it works.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't work because you try to execute selectpicker() before the selectpicker plugin is loaded. Where are you including bootstrap-elect.js ?

Comment: No mistake showed. I execute selectpicker when document is ready and also this script is at the bottom of the page (after bootstrap-select)

Answer (score 20):

You need to call the initialising function after the DOM is ready.  This is usually done as part of a `$(document).ready()` function block.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

When you are attempting the command via the console, the DOM is already loaded and available. As such the call works.  The above code sample should work similarly.

Comment: `$( function() {` is equal to `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: if I set interval of 3 seconds before run the selectpicker method - it works. I just need to launch this method after angular full bootstraped.

Comment: It is likely that the function is being called before the jquery/boostrap includes.  Ensure that they are available before running this.  Also, check you console for the error message generated when the above code is run.

Answer (score 14):

After 1 year I had the same issue. This worked for me:

1-Downloaded the zip files at owner site -  http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

2-CSS, inside head tag->2files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="yourPath/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-83d5a1b/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css">
<link href="yourPath/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

3-Js files, at the end before close body tag.

```
<body>
<select class="selectpicker">
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
  </select> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="yourPath/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourPath/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourPath/silviomoreto-bootstrap-select-83d5a1b/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
  });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        style: 'btn-info',
        size: 4   
    });
});
```

Should work fine

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `bootstrap-select.js` or `bootstrap-select.min.js` is included before loading your code.

```
<script src="path-to/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That was the issue on my end

Answer (score 2):

There will be some reasons that it will not work.
Reason 1:

if bootstrap-select.css take time to load, then already the loaded jquery command like $(document).ready(function () {})  will don't know the function so it will throw an error.

solution:
So,inorder to overcome this just give         `$('your selector').selectpicker();`
in between the script tag at the end of html code with out any jquery ready function... for sure it will work

Comment: thanks, it worked. Actually I placed ```$('your selector').selectpicker();``` after body tag and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({
        style: 'btn-default',
        size: false
    });
});
```

Have the same issue, this (set default size) helped me. Without settings menu is not showing.

`The size option is set to 'auto' by default. When size is set to 'auto', the menu always opens up to show as many items as the window will allow without being cut off. Set size to false to always show all items. The size of the menu can also be specifed using the data-size attribute.` http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/

ADDED:
Also don't forget about bootsrap version, I search around and found that this plugin works with 2.3.2 bootstrap version at official page it has such link. So I think i can be trouble too.

Answer (score -9):

This worked for me, if i delete this

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Soo strange...