# Bootstrap selectpicker problems - no dropdown menu appears

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, blazor

I am using Blazor and trying to include this: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/ plugin.

When the page loads, there is no menu to be seen. But when I enter:

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
```

into the DevTools console, the menu appears.
A question very similar to mine is: [Bootstrap-select not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17941749/bootstrap-select-not-working/17942784), and I have tried to implement some of these solutions to no avail.
Here is my html (in the _Host.cshtml file):

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>SystematicReviewlution</title>
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.css">
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-select-1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
```

And here is where I use the selectpicker class:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple>
    <option>Mustard</option>
    <option>Ketchup</option>
    <option>Relish</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not how blazor works. In earlier technologies they used to have dom load so that you can run certain javascript methods or initialize certain plugins when document is loaded either using vanilla javascript or jQuery.

```
function initSelectPicker()
{ 
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
}

window.onload = initSelectPicker();
```

or

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
});
```

In blazor things works differently. To integrate third-party UI Component you require to call javascript method from blazor [Learn how to Call JavaScript functions from .NET methods in ASP.NET Core Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0). After setting up the prerequisites you need to write an interop method just like below in your JS file.

```
window.selectPickerService = {
    init: () => {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    }
}
```

From your components you can next call your javascript interop methods in following way.

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime 

protected override Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    if(firstRender)
    {
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("selectPickerService.init");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use bootstrap like this:

```
<div class="dropdown">
   <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" @onclick="ToggleDropdown">
      Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="@myclass">
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
     <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then code down:

```
 @code{
    bool Isshow = false;
    string myclass => "dropdown-menu" + (Isshow ? " show" : "");
    void ToggleDropdown()
    {

        Isshow = !Isshow;
    }
}
```

See bootstarp [page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/)

Comment: Thank you - I wanted to use the selectpicker class to make use of the multiple-select and data-live-search bar, instead of the dropdown class. Sorry for not making that clear in the question.

Comment: Did you try to use "DropDownDataGrid with multiple selection and multiple columns" of Radzen, I think is very easy to use!